# Analyze custom functions on String

Tags: android, graph, plot

I want create a program for Android to plot functions.
To plot the graphics I think it's better to use canvas, right?
But one problem is: how do I read one string, like `y = cos(x^2) + log(x)`?
I already created a program in C to plot graphics, but it was limited: the functions were inserted in source code.
Example: to plot a linear function:

```
i = 0;
for (int x = Xmin; x <= Xmax; x++) {
  resultstable[i][1] = m * x + a;
  resultstable[i][0] = x;
  i++;
}
```

And later I plot the points of the table.

But, what I need is to instead ask the user for a function, save it as a string, analyze it for search functions and calc the images of objects, respecting precedences, parentheses, etc.
I thought maybe first ask the type of function, and then request `m` and `a` for linear function, but this is basic and I just want to create the program to learn more than I already know, not to publish, etc.

Any ideas? Links? Material?

Comment: I want say *canvas. But Android thinks he know more than me. Thanks for correct my errors Mike! May the gods bless you!

Comment: I found one post (http://blog.joaomorais.com.br/2008/02/10/construindo_interpretador_oo.html) about the topic. For now, i could take some ideas, but is still very misty...